# Generating random numbers in big table causes crash

Tags: c++, arrays, random, crash, mingw

I needed to generate random numbers into a big table for a very simple program and it kept crashing (This program has stopped working, windows is looking for a solution etc) and I managed to isolate it to this code below. If tableSizeY is 103 or lower, it runs all fine, but 104 or higher makes my computer crash. To my understanding, only the first row is getting filled with random numbers and all others are empty, so I find it quite odd...

I am using MinGW 4.9.1 inside Sublime Text 2, on Windows 8.1, 8go ram, if that has anything to do with it.

Also, completely new to programming so I might be overlooking some very trivial things, obviously.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        int const tableSizeX (5000);
        int const tableSizeY (104);
        int table[tableSizeX][tableSizeY];
        //Launch rand generator
        srand(time(NULL));

        for (int i; i<tableSizeX; ++i)
        {
                table[i][0] = rand() % 10 + 1;
                cout << i+1 << " = " << table[i][0] << endl;
        }

        getchar();
}
```

Comment: You most probably have a stack overflow at this line `int table[tableSizeX][tableSizeY];`.

Comment: Your OS may not be giving your process sufficient stack for such a large object... try allocating it dynamically using `new`, or (much better) use `std::vector`, or checking how to request more stack.

Comment: Do you have access to Boost (www.boost.org)? I know it's a leap for a beginner but they do have a very good matrix library. Let me know if not as there is another approach you could take. By the way, taking the modulus of `rand()` is, statistically speaking, a bad idea as it introduces a bias unless the periodicity of your generator is a multiple of, in your case, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating a large amount of data on the stack. Consider [dynamically allocating](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/) it:

```
int const tableSizeX (5000);
int const tableSizeY (104);

int **table;
table = new int*[tableSizeX];
for (int i = 0; i < tableSizeX; i++) {
    table[i] = new int[tableSizeY];
}

//Launch rand generator
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i; i<tableSizeX; ++i)
{
    table[i][0] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    cout << i+1 << " = " << table[i][0] << endl;
}

// Now you also need to free the memory ...
for (int i = 0; i < tableSizeX; i++) {
    delete[] table[i];
}
delete[] table;

getchar();
```

A more common C++ alternative would be using `std::vector` which would get you rid of all the more C-specific pointer wizardry ...

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > table;
```

As a dirty quick fix you could also make `table` a global variable.

Comment: You can just use `auto` or `unique_ptr` (smart pointers), for having problem with `delete`

Comment: @sop Of course you could. But smart pointers are probably more of an advanced topic ...

Comment: @dragosht: The modern consensus is that `delete`  is the advanced topic, because it's hard to get it right in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You probably exceed the default stack size of your program...
You could use

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,N
```

where N is the required stack size in bytes.. 
Assuming sizeof(int) gives you 4 - you would need more than 4*104*5000 bytes.

Another way, would be to dynamically allocate the required memory:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> table(tableSizeX,std::vector<int>(tableSizeY));
```

Answer (score 0):

The default compiler stack limit is 1MB. Try using dynamic memory instead. This should allow your program to run without any hiccups.

Use the new keyword to allocate the memory onto the heap, and just be sure to call delete[] in this case once you are done using the memory.

Comment: On what compiler? While this is not bad advice per se, it's not the greatest practice. In C++ we typically use `std::vector` or an appropriate container.

Comment: The default stack limit is 1MB on most compilers. I personally use Visual Studios where this is also true. And in regards to using vectors vs. 2D array, neither is better in this situation because we don't know what the user is trying to due with the data besides store random numbers. To truly find the best container, we'd need to know what the intent of the data is and analyze memory vs. speed because with a data set this size, using a graph, hash table, binary search tree, etc... may be more efficient than just a vector or 2D array.

Comment: @user3851179: AFAIK the default is 64K or so on Linux, but stack growth also works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you exhausted the memory allocated for you in the stack , try allocating it in the heap.

You have a lot of choices to choose from.

1) You can use a pointer  - the problem is you have to manually delete it before the program exits or else you will have memory leak.

2) auto_ptr - just like a pointer but this will actually delete itself when it get's out of scope ( which means when you pass this pointer of a function after that function call since it's already out of scope it will automatically delete itself)

3)boost::shared_ptr - it's hard to explain this one but actually works like an auto_ptr except that it will not automatically deletes itself when it gets out of scope, it has a control block which increments when it's passed to another function or some sort of another scope then decrements when that instance gets out of scope. It only deletes itself when the counter reaches zero.

Your call . shared_ptr works like a charm once you get to learn how to use it.